# Java 8 Streams causing errors in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to Jenkins and am trying to set it up on Ubuntu to build my Java project with gradle when I make a commit. Currently, when I build my Java project with gradle through the command line, the build is fine. However, when Jenkins tries to build it, I get "error: illegal start of expression" wherever I've used a Java 8 stream/forEach.

My Jenkins instance is hosted on the same user profile instead of a separate one and is thus using the same version of OpenJDK. Is there any reason why the build fails in Jenkins but succeeds when I run gradle manually?

Comment: It clearly isn't using the same JDK that you have on your local machine. It has to be Java 8 for the Streams API.

Comment: Do you know how I could change it then? When I run java -version on my local machine and as a Jenkins build step, they both have the same output: 
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~15.10.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: Get on the Jenkins machine and check its JAVA_HOME variable. Check your Jenkins setup, etc. Whatever Jenkins is doing, it's using an older version of the JDK silently. Probably worth adding that comment info into the body of your question for others to see.

Comment: On Jenkins, you can see the Java version it is using in "Manage Jenkins" then "System Information"

Comment: Yup, that was it! Jenkins was using Java 7 by default instead. Fixed by adjusting the path to point to the installed Java 8. Thanks!